# Gracenote daily lookup limit

Tags: gracenote

I'm getting this error:

```
gnsdk_musicid_query_find_albums FAILED 
Reason: GCSP: Hello error: [1010] The Gracenote ODP 05556 [Name: Firstname Lastname] [App: Appname] application has reached is daily lookup limit with Gracenote. You may try again tomorrow or may contact Gracenote support at support@gracenote.com. 
[Gracenote Error: <ERR>]
```

I contacted support@gracenote.com and I was asked to post my question on Stack Overflow.

```
Thank you for writing.  We are providing community support on Stack Overflow (www.stackoverflow.com). This provides a convenient way for the Gracenote Developer community to find, follow and track questions or issues with our SDK's and API's.

If you have any specific technical questions regarding our SDK's or API's, including installation, usage or bug reports, please ask them on Stack Overflow (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and use the 'gracenote' tag. Using this tag will allow other community members, including Gracenote Developer Support to find and respond to your questions.
```

So, I'm posting my question here.

Can you let me know what the limit is and if there is a way to get this limit increased?

Answer (score 0):

In general, your query limit is variable and may depend on system availability. We will contact you for more detail about how you are using our services. From there, lets see if we can find a way to satisfy your needs.